# Angular 2 - How to instantiate multiple services in a component with specific order?

Tags: design-patterns, service, angular

I'm looking for a way to instantiate multiple services in a component with specific order.

For example, let's say I have 3 services namely time, device, and data services which data service is subscribing to 'time_range' and 'device_list' observables of time and device services to update its data. These 3 services are instantiated in MainComponent after login and this component only requires data service's 'data' for its view.

That means data service should be instantiated before time and device services so that it will be able to detect the changes of time and device services when they're instantiated (initialized in constructor).

I have included those services in "providers: []" of "@Component" decorator of MainComponent and I have no idea how to instantiate data service before other services. I tried changing the order of providers' array but there's no difference in result.

Instantiating data service to AppComponent or on bootstrap would work but I don't want it to exist in larger scope.

I'm new to angular 2 and not sure if I understood the concept of service and component right so I would really appreciate to receive feedbacks of this way of service doing all the logic to provide the data and components just fetching the data from the right service and display to its view.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Angular2 DI you can't specify the order. DI figures the order out by itself as far as the dependencies require a specific order.

Besides that, your code shouldn't depend on a specific order of instantiation.

You can for example use `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject` for subscribers to get the last emitted value in case they subscribe after the sender already emitted the first event or otherwise react on new subscriptions.

Comment: BehaviorSubject was something that I was looking for! For those who're looking for more info, please refer to this doc: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/7efcdc99973d496b70702eb6a40dd384a2e702c4/doc/subject.md